# I have created an integration app for gdrive and it required to generate token on user behalf, but it requires Domain wide delegation for that

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-drive-api

I have created an integration app for gdrive and it required to generate token on user behalf, but it requires Domain wide delegation for that, but getting the domain wide delegation requires manual intervention from admin, it is possible to automate these getting domain wide delegation access for my service account associated with my app.
And also is this changed recently, as we published similar apps in year 2018 and we didn't required to get domain wide delegation manually from admins

Get domain wide delegation for apps without manual intervention from Admins

Comment: Only a Google Workspace Super Admin can grant permission. https://support.google.com/a/answer/2405986

Comment: @JohnHanley is it possible to automate this process?

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking. To grant permission to a service account requires a Super Admin. Once the permission to impersonate has been granted, the service account can then impersonate any identity in the Google Workspace account. Are your users members of your Workspace account? If not, you cannot use a service account to impersonate at all.